# Where are the "local files" for the Localization Update module stored?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm using the [Localization Update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module in Drupal 7.  As the "update source", I can choose "Local files and remote server".  I'd like to add some .po files that I created locally; where do I place them so that l10n_update can pick them up?

I don't see any options on the module's configuration page (/admin/config/regional/language/update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the bottom of the module's configuration page you have to set a path for the local files.

> **Store downloaded files** A path relative to the Drupal installation directory where translation files will be stored, e.g.
>   sites/all/translations. Saved translation files can be reused by other
>   installations. If left empty the downloaded translation will not be
>   saved.

Comment: Ok, I see.  I didn't realized that the "downloaded files" and the "local files" were the same thing.